# Polynomial functors, Type Theory and Homotopy

Tags: category-theory, type-theory, functors, homotopy-type-theory

I am finding that there is a bit of a battle going on to provide a "foundation" of Type Theory, and perhaps for Mathematics, either with polynomial functors or Homotopy Type Theory.  There is a [nice table here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_theory#Key_concepts) that compares Homotopy Theory, based on spaces, to Type Theory.  It would be great to get something similar for Polynomial Functors and Type Theory.  Is this possible?  The question is, how can we summarize how polynomial functors are used as a model of Type Theory?